# turtle hop between doors

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I draw a turtle which is hopping between doors

1. To visual the doors I need to draw X with numbers which each number represent a door, how do I draw line with numbers from 1 to 100 underneath ?
2. How to draw half a circle to visual the step ? instead of just an arrow that goes backwards over a line

edit #1 :

[image]

expected result : 
for movement = [4, 8, 7, 15]

```
0 4 (40.00,0.00)
1 8 (80.00,0.00)
2 7 (70.00,0.00)
3 15 (150.00,-0.00)
```

result is :

```
0 4 (40.00,0.00)
1 8 (80.00,0.00)
2 7 (240.00,0.00)
3 15 (100.00,-0.00)
```

updated code :

```
import turtle
from time import sleep

canvas = turtle.Screen()
canvas.title('')
canvas.setup(900, 400)
DELTA = 10
movement = [4, 8, 7, 15]
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
t.goto(movement[0] * DELTA, 0)
t.pendown()


def write_step(n):
    t.penup()
    px_distance = 20
    t.forward(px_distance)
    t.write("{}".format(n))
    t.back(px_distance)
    t.pendown()


for i, step in enumerate(movement):
    print(i, step, t.pos())
    if i > 0:
        if movement[i - 1] > step:
            t.left(90)
            t.circle(step * DELTA, -180)
        else:
            t.right(90)
            t.circle(step * DELTA, 180)
        write_step(i)
    else:
        t.forward(step * DELTA)
    t.setheading(0)
    sleep(1)

canvas.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import turtle
from time import sleep

canvas = turtle.Screen()
canvas.title('')
canvas.setup(1800, 300)
DELTA = 10
movement = [5, 15, 10, 25, 50, 40]
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
for i in range(100):
    t2.goto(i * DELTA, -50)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        t2.write(i)
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
t.goto(movement[0] * DELTA, 0)
t.pendown()


def write_step(n):
    t.penup()
    px_distance = 20
    t.forward(px_distance)
    t.write("{}".format(n))
    t.back(px_distance)
    t.pendown()

for i, step in enumerate(movement):
    if step != movement[-1]:
        distance = 0
        next_move = movement[i + 1]
        if next_move > step:
            distance = DELTA * (next_move - step)
            t.right(90)
            t.circle(distance / 2, -180)
        else:
            distance = DELTA * (step - next_move)
            t.left(90)
            t.circle(distance / 2, 180)
        write_step(i + 1)
    t.setheading(0)
    sleep(0.1)

canvas.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an arc using the turtle.circle command but with an extra parameter to represent 180 degrees. You can write the numbers using turtle.write.

For example:

```
import turtle
from time import sleep

movement = [2, 5, 8, 4, 10, 3]

for i, step in enumerate(movement):
    if i > 0:
        if movement[i - 1] < step:
            #turtle.forward(step * 10)
            turtle.left(90)
        else:
            turtle.right(90)
        turtle.circle(step*10, 180)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(10)
        turtle.write("{}".format(i))
        turtle.back(10)
        turtle.pendown()
    else:
        turtle.forward(step * 10)
    turtle.setheading(0)
    sleep(1)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: thank you for the help, edited my code, it moves more than it should on x-axis

Answer (score 1):

This might be a situation where `setworldcoordinates()` simplifies your logic and gives you what you really want:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ("Arial", 12, "normal")

def write_step(n, turtle):
    turtle.penup()
    y = turtle.ycor()
    turtle.sety(-7)
    turtle.write(n, align="center", font=FONT)
    turtle.sety(y)
    turtle.pendown()

canvas = Screen()
canvas.title('')
canvas.setup(1800, 300)
canvas.setworldcoordinates(0, -10, 100, 10)

movement = [5, 15, 10, 25, 50, 40]

yertle = Turtle(shape="circle")

for n in range(100):
    yertle.goto(n, -9)
    if n % 5 == 0:
        yertle.write(n, align="center", font=FONT)

yertle.penup()
yertle.hideturtle()
yertle.goto(movement[0], -5)
yertle.showturtle()
yertle.pendown()

for i, step in enumerate(movement):
    if step != movement[-1]:
        distance = 0
        next_move = movement[i + 1]
        if next_move > step:
            distance = next_move - step
            yertle.right(90)
            yertle.circle(distance / 2, -180, steps=60)
        else:
            distance = step - next_move
            yertle.left(90)
            yertle.circle(distance / 2, 180, steps=60)
        write_step(i + 1, yertle)
    yertle.setheading(0)

canvas.exitonclick()
```